# Modeling a proportion using longitudinal data

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, panel-data, proportion

To illustrate my question I'll make a (very) fictional example.

I have a set of 17 year old people that every year report how many cigarettes they smoked and how many miles they ran. Very few of those people will eventually be selected as Olympiads athletes.

This setting gives us a data set of this kind:

```
|subj  |  age  |  cigarettes  | miles | will_be_olymp
+------+-------+--------------+-------+--------------
1        17       1             100      1
1        18       15            233      1
1        19       300           187      1
1        20       237           200      1
2        17       0             567      0
2        18       10            123      0
...
```

Now, assuming that age is not influential (for example, those boys are immortal elves), how do I model the probability of getting selected for the olympiads subject to the variables `cigarettes` and `miles`?

My idea was to run a logistic regression of this kind:

```
will_be_olymp ~ a + b*cigarettes +  c*miles
```

where `a` is an intercept term. However, there is an obvious problem. This model ignores that those measures are correlated (as they come from the same subject, at a different age).

One way to solve this problem (I think) would be to get a single random sample per subject, but this would require me to get an insane amount of measurements (to sample the space `miles` and `cigarettes`), and I would waste most of the data collected.

Also, a single subject may contribute more than once for a certain value of `miles` or `cigarettes`.

What is the correct way to model this situation that leverages all the longitudinal measurements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of years is small compared to the number of subjects, then it may be reasonable to use a logistic regression model as you describe, but with a separate term for each year, i.e.

```
will_be_olymp ~ a + b1*cig1 + ... + b4*cig4 + c1*miles1 + ... + c4*miles4
```

where `cig1`, ..., `cig4` represent the number of cigarettes smoked at age 17, ..., 20, respectively.

On the other hand, if the number of years is large (or if there are multiple observations per year), then this may require an excessive number of parameters. In this case, a *functional logistic regression* model may be more appropriate: see, for example, this recent paper on the topic, [Functional logistic regression approach to detecting gene by longitudinal environmental exposure interaction in a case-control study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25219575).